# Create a container object, then add an image object into that container object after it has been created

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

```
form_image_container = ImageContainerForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
if form_image_container.is_valid():
    instance_container = form_image_container.save(commit=False)
    instance_container.user = request.user
    instance_container.save()

    return redirect(# redirect to the recently created canvas page)
    # somehow need to create image container first, then add the a image into the image container
    form_image = ImageForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form_image.is_valid():
        instance_image = form_image.save(commit=False)
        instance_image.user = request.user
        instance_image.image_container = instance_container
        instance_image.image = obj.image
        instance_image.save()
```

Is there a way to create the first object (container for images) and then add the second object (image) into the first (container for images)

Comment: sorry i took so long. unfortunately it didn't work. is it because the image_container needs to be created first before the image can be added into that image_container?

Comment: yes, but my code does show it being created first

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: yeah, the image_container gets created but the image is not being saved into it.

Comment: yeah, i managed to get it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combinging two forms into one always leads to complications.  But your trouble is because you are returning halfway through!! please change your code as follows

```
form_image_container = ImageContainerForm(request.POST,request.FILES) # or None is redundant

    if form_image_container.is_valid():
        instance_container = form_image_container.save(commit=False)
        instance_container.user = request.user
        instance_container.save()

        form_image = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
        if form_image.is_valid():
            instance_image = form_image.save(commit=False)
            instance_image.user = request.user
            instance_image.image_container = instance_container
            instance_image.image = obj.image
            instance_image.save()
            return redirect(# redirect to the recently created canvas page)
            # somehow need to create image container first, then add the a image 

    return render(request, form_image_container)
```

Note that this still wont work unless your `ImageContainerForm` has fields that overlap with `ImageForm` which makes the second form pretty much redundant anyway!

I think you may probably be looking for `Formsets`, or breaking up the process into two different forms.